# How to improve performance for large quantity subscribes using WebSocket Client C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, optimization, websocket

I am using c# (.NET 7)

In my case, I use large quantity connection and much more subscribes for receive information.
I noticed that it takes a lot of power CPU, use it every second and thougth about optimization performance.

Receive information every second but in my case, enough takes 1 time in 10 - 20 seconds so I figure out to use *Thread.Sleep()* and this working well but exist one problem. During use *Thread.Sleep()* came message and containing somewhere, after finished *Thread.Sleep()* those contained old messages supplied me.

For resolved the current problem I tried to use other libraries for WebSocket

1. Websocket.Client
2. System.Net.WebSockets
3. WebSocketSharp-netstandard

And received the same result.

Secondly, I loaded the library https://source.dot.net/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/ProjectExplorer.html, got access to code-related WebSocket and tried to find a place that contained those messages during the use of *Thread.Sleep* but didn't find it, look like this place locate in HttpClient layer and realy hard import it all correct for check it.

And finally played with Observable.

I expecting use *Thread.Sleep* or something similar approach for optimizing performance.
What do you recommend to me to optimize performance?

Simple example

```
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@depth5@1000ms");
WebsocketClient client = new WebsocketClient(serviceUri);
var iterator = 0;
client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(type =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Text);

    iterator++;
    if (iterator >= 5)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        iterator = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: thread::sleep() makes your thread to stop and do nothing for that amount of time, so it is the very antithesis of performance. Your issue is more likely in the work you're doing upon receipt of a message, or perhaps you are polling instead of blocking, Since you haven't shared the code, there's nothing anyone can do to help.